# When I run this program I ran into an error, I don't know what's the main issue here, if there is a mistake plz let me know. error say unbound method

Tags: python, dictionary

dist = {"name": "huzaifa", "age": 18, "skill": "programmer"}
print(dist)
for key in dict.keys():
print(value)

error:
TypeError: unbound method dict.items() needs an argument

Comment: There's a typo in your code, it should be `dist.keys()` . To access the values, you need `print(dist[key])`

Comment: For one thing `"dist" != "dict"`...

Comment: I don't believe this code produces that error.

Comment: Ohh thanks that was a silly mistake acctually, which made me stressed, thanks Alot who ever helped.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print the keys you have to do it like below.

```
dist = {"name": "huzaifa", "age": 18, "skill": "programmer"}
print(dist)
for key in dist.keys():
    print(key)
```

If you want to get values you can do it like below.

```
dist = {"name": "huzaifa", "age": 18, "skill": "programmer"}
print(dist)
for value in dist.values():
    print(value)
```

If you want to get both you can do it as below.

```
dist = {"name": "huzaifa", "age": 18, "skill": "programmer"}
print(dist)
for key, value in dist.items():
    print(f'Key: {key}')
    print(f'Value: {value}')
```